# Webpack externals module name with hyphen

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router, webpack

I'm trying to load angular-ui-router in Webpack as an external dependency. The module name is "angular-ui-router". Here's an example:

```
module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    ...
    externals: {
        'angular': true,
        'angular-ui-router': true
    },
    ...
});
```

The problem with this is that Webpack creates a module in my app.bundle.js that looks like the following:

```
/***/ },
/* 1 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    module.exports = angular;

/***/ },
/* 2 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

    module.exports = angular-ui-router;

/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

When the browser tries to load the module, it evaluates `module.exports = angular-ui-router` as an expression, throwing the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: ui is not defined`

The only fix I have found for this issue is:

```
module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    ...
    externals: {
        'angular': true,
        'angular-ui-router': 'window["angular-ui-router"]'
    },
    ...
});
```

This yields the correct result.

Is there a better way?

Comment: There's no better way, really. It's annoying that `window` isn't implied for the simple externals boolean option, but that does make it useful when targeting things other than browser scripts (like web worker scripts, for example, which have no `window`).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, so I got it solved using something like this

```
module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    ...
    externals: [
      ....
      'angular-ui-router': {
                   commonjs: 'angular-ui-router' 
          }
        }
        ],
    ...
});
```

Comment: What if the module in question is an ES2015 module (`import` style)?

Answer (score -1):

When you have externals module name with hyphen use the **libraryTarget as umd** in the output section. So the app.bundle code would have

```
require("angular-ui-router") would be used for requireJS and 
root.angularUIRouter = factory(root["angular-ui-router"]) would be used for global variable type.
```

Bundle code would look like this:

```
"object" == typeof exports && "object" == typeof module ? 
module.exports = factory(require("angular-ui-router")) : "function" == 
typeof define && define.amd ? define(["angular-ui-router"], factory) : 
"object" == typeof exports ? exports.temp = factory(require("angular-ui-
router")) : root.temp = factory(root["angular-ui-router"])
```